# Measuring the time taken for some function calls

Tags: c++

I want to measure the time taken by a few functions like opening a file or locking a mutex

So far I narrowed my search to

```
    high_resolution_clock
```

But it gives the result time of the function while I want the time result of time taken by the user and the time taken by the system separated

If I can use high_resolution_clock for that , then how? And if not what can I use?

Comment: C++ is generic, it doesn't know anything about the underlying system, and can therefore not handle things like "system time" or "user time". For that you need to use native and non-portable functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to measure the time taken by your program (at execution time ) , you can use

```
high_resulution_clock

#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
```

for example if you want to measure how long takes the execution of your function:

```
void func()
```

you can use the following code:

```
high_resulution_clock::time_point t1, t2;
double duration;
t1 = high_resulution_clock::now()
func();
t2 = high_resulution_clock::now()
duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(t2-t1).count();
```

Now in duration you have the measure of the time passed between the call of now() for t1 and the call of now() for t2, this means the time of execution of func().

Of course this method does not give you the exact time that the function takes but it gives you a great approximation, it is useful if you're trying to compare performs between different data structures with different amount of data.

So if you want to measure the time taken by a user (in a certain part of your program) you can use the code above, using a function that requires user input.

I hope I have helped,as much as I can, if you want to learn more about chrono, to understand what function and representation of time is the best for your case: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/high_resolution_clock/now/